# golang-grpc service - import types from another file

Tags: go, module, namespaces, protocol-buffers, grpc

In my project I have a `service_x.proto` file for each service and a `types.proto` file for types shared across all services. However, when I compile for go, it puts them in separate packages; I also can't put `go_package = 'service_x'` at the top of the `types.proto` file because it will change for every service `x` where it is used. What is the cleanest way to compile my service and have access to the message types from `types.proto` in `service_a.pb.go`? Here is an example setup:

`service_a.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package service_a;

import "types.proto";

service ServiceA {
  rpc SomeRPC (SomeRPCRequest) returns (types.Result)
}

message SomeRPCRequest {
  string x = 1;
}
```

`types.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package types;

message Result {
  bool success = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can import the types.proto in the service_a.proto file and use it

for example

```
syntax = "proto3";
package service_a;

//add this line 
import "types.proto"

service ServiceA {
  rpc SomeRPC (SomeRPCRequest) returns (types.Result)
}

message SomeRPCRequest {
  string x = 1;
}
```

you can read more here https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#importing-definitions

Comment: sorry, I already am importing the types.proto -- corrected above. The problem is that protoc creates two packages, and the one for service_a doesn't reference the package types.

Comment: @DanJenson, correct me if I am wrong 2 packages means 2 package of seperate dto one containing types and other containing SomeRPCRequest ? 

SideNote: I think you have to use `Result` without the `types.`

Comment: no, 'types.Result' is correct; and you're right, it's in two packages -- I don't want that, or I want a clean way for protoc to generate a reference to the latter.

Comment: Yeah I have had that issue, 
You can use type alias that way it will not allow protoc to generate the same dto again.

Comment: @DanJenson If you do not want two packages, simply do not declare two packages.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by making both proto files part of the 'pb' package; they can then be compiled to the same output directory (i.e. pb) and have access to symbols defined in both.